# How can I prove that $\frac{21n -3}{4}$ and $\frac{15n+2}{4}$ are never both integers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have converted this to a problem of modular arithmetic.
I seek to prove that $21n-3$ and $15n+2$ are never congruent to $0\pmod 4$ for the same value of $n$.

I observed that $21n$ is $\{1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0\}$ about $\pmod 4$, and that $21n- 3$ is $\{2,3,0,1,2,3,0\}$. Similarly, $15n+2$ is $\{1,2,3,0,1,2,3\}$.

Thus for the same $n$ they are never congruent $\pmod 4$. How can I put this into a rigorous mathematical argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are integer for some $n$, the difference also will be integer, but:
$$(21n -3)/4 - (15n+2)/4 = (6n-5)/4 = 3n/2 - 1 - 1/4.$$

Comment: I think it's a little bit nicer to look at the sum.

Answer (score 2):

If $21n-3=0\mod 4$ then we get $21n=3\implies n=3\mod 4$

If $15n+2=0\mod 4$ then we get $15n=-2\implies -n=-2\implies n=2 \mod4$

the congruences $n=2,3\mod 4$ can not be solved simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that $21n-3$ is odd for every even $n$ because

odd*odd=odd and odd*even=even

$15n+2$ is vice versa: Only odd for odd $n$

Thus $21n-3$ and $15n+2$ can never by even for the same $n$...

Comment: Neat parity argument

Answer (score 2):

Adding them you get an integer of the form $9n -\frac 1 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Euclid's algorithm. Since 
\begin{align*}
21n-3&=1\cdot (15n+2)+(6n-5)\\
15n+2&=2\cdot (6n-5)+(3n+12)\\
6n-5&=2\cdot (3n+12)-29,
\end{align*}
$29$ needs to be divisible by $4$ if numbers from the question are both integers. That is not true.

Comment: What is this algorithm ?